# How to declare good old C-Array in Objective-C inline?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

this is my piece of code:

```
NSUInteger indexArr[] = {1,2,3,4};

NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:indexArr length:4];
```

Is there a way to declare the indexArr inline, like

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:{1,2,3,4} length:4];
```

or something?
It's because I'm writing a test with some reference Paths and I want to save lines of code that are not usefull for anybody...

Best regards, hijolen

Comment: Tip: The `length` parameter could be passed the value of `sizeof(indexArr)/sizeof(indexArr[0])`. Helps avoid mistakes in the future when people add/remove an element or two.

Comment: thats perfect... :) thank you... my code keeps getting better and better...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only problem with your attempt is that you need to cast it so that the compiler knows it is the right type.

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:(NSUInteger[]){1,2,3,4} length:4];
```

Comment: Note that this syntax is a GCC-ism.