# Passing CGFloat array in core graphics

Tags: ios, core-graphics

There are many functions in core graphics that take the pointer ie. pointer of array such as 
**CGContextSetFillColor(context, colors);**. I have to create the value for the array colors everytime and then pass the pointer to the function as;

```
CGFloat colors[] = {1.0, 0.0, 0., 1.0};
CGContextSetFillColor(context, colors);
```

But, it would be much easier if I could pass the values directly into the functions like;

```
CGContextSetFillColor(context, {1.0, 0.0, 0., 1.0});
```

The above syntax is not correct and the compiler complains about it, I have very limited understanding of how pointers work in C. So I would like to ask what is the correct way to pass the values directly in the same line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6771284/892696) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771263/how-to-declare-good-old-c-array-in-objective-c-inline) you can do this:

```
CGContextSetFillColor(context, (CGFloat[]){1.0, 0.0, 0., 1.0});
```